# Update userpositon to server periodically using Endpoints

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, google-cloud-endpoints

I would like to update my users position to a Google Endpoint in Google App Engine periodically.
The fact that I'm using Endpoints is important, because that's why I cant simply use an `IntentService` and `AlarmManger` to schedule the task.

The problem is the following:
To update the position to the server I need some Objects which are not accessible in a Service.
Let me try to sketch it:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    [...]
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        endpointsHandler.updatePosition()
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Here I need an objects of my `EndpointsHandler`. I cannot simply create a new object, because it depends on some other objects like `GoogleApiClient`.

But I cannot add the objects to the Server because when I initialize the `AlarmManager` there is no way to pass objects

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent updaterIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, updaterIntent, 0);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SOME_PERIOD, SOME_PERIOD, pendingIntent);
```

I could pass the objects as in the Intent, but besides the fact that all classes (even `GoogleApiClient`) have to implement `Parceable`, I don't thing this is a very good way. I'm sure there is a clean way which I am just not able to find.

Comment: It's not a good idea to serialize these objects as they might contain something that's not serializable. Why don't you just create a fresh GoogleApiClient?

Comment: Create a new GoogleApiClient would be possible but it would be a very bad way since the creation takes very long and it would need much resources to create a new object on very period.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own.
But since I didn't find any solution like this on SO, i'll post it here:

I used the way descriped [here](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/).
I created a central Controller-Class which keeps all important objects of my app. This class is a subclass of `android.app.Application`.
In the Manifest-File I added

```
<application
    [...]
    android:name=".controllers.AppController">
```

To declare to use my custom application class.
Now in each Activity and Service I can use `getApplication()` to get the Object of my Application-Class.